# Angular 5 - Update directive attribute value on click

Tags: angular, angular5

I have a progress bar built alongside a form which has a stepper process. Each time the user clicks 'Next' or 'Previous' they will see a different part of the form.

I need the progress bar to update it's value depending on what step they are on. Or simply enough when the user clicks 'Next' the progress bar updates it's value.

```
<mdb-progressbar value="25" min="0" max="100" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></mdb-progressbar>
```

value="25" must update to value="50" on the next step and so on.

What's the best way to update this attribute in angular 4/5?

Thanks

Comment: I get it what you are trying to achieve.
But have you heard about routes?

Comment: Are you suggesting to update the route on each step of the process?

Comment: Yes. create child route of main route. and use components for showing different forms.

Comment: This is not what I want, because it's one form but different steps

Comment: yes. you can divide form in different steps. In my technique, it will be same form.

Comment: @Zayn look at my answer : you must use an input and increment the value of that input on every step completion.